# Rename/recode multiple excel file names based on reference

Tags: r

I have 192 xlsx files that are named based on the equipment SN. Due to the time involved to manually rename these files, I would like to find a way to rename them faster. For example, I would like to rename file "65_sample.xlsx" as file "S1_5.xlsx". The new file names will be used to further subdivide the data by location. Essentially, I have a list of 192 spreadsheets that I would like to rename as something more useful for analysis.

The desired end result is a dataframe in r with all the data combined, with a column that specifies the original spreadsheet (in this case, that column is "location"). I have compiled the spreadsheets and created a dataframe (the code is provided below). I am looking for a more efficient way of renaming the spreadsheets or, more importantly, recoding the spreadsheet names and adding them as a column in the dataframe. There is no pattern in the original file names that can be used for renaming or identification.

The individual spreadsheets are laid out as:

```
Date/Time   Unit    Value
3/14/2022 8:00  C   20.978
3/14/2022 9:00  C   20.978
3/14/2022 10:00 C   20.978
3/14/2022 11:00 C   20.978
3/14/2022 12:00 C   21.354
3/14/2022 13:00 C   21.416
3/14/2022 14:00 C   21.541
3/14/2022 15:00 C   21.666
3/14/2022 16:00 C   21.416
3/14/2022 17:00 C   21.041
3/14/2022 18:00 C   20.853
3/14/2022 19:00 C   20.603
```

I have an excel spreadsheet of the original file names ("SN Number") and what I would like the new spreadsheet to read ("new"):

```
SN Number   new 
65_sample   S1_5
75_sample   S1_10
85_sample   S1_20
```

Here is the code I have used to combine the spreadsheets and create a new column for the filename ("location"):

```
files<-list.files(path = ".",
                  pattern = ".xlsx")

columns<-c("Date","C","value","location")
BF_soil_temp_21<-setNames(do.call(rbind,Map(`cbind`, 
                                      lapply(files, read.xlsx), V4=files)), columns)
```

Ideally, the dataframe would look like the following, where location refers to the updated file name ("new" in the example above) instead of the original file name ("SN number" in the example above):

```
Date/Time   Unit    Value   location
3/14/2022 12:00 C   1   S 1_5
3/15/2022 12:00 C   21  S 1_10
3/16/2022 12:00 C   22  S 1_20
3/17/2022 12:00 C   23  S 1_5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `for loop` solution. I created three identical .xlsx files based on your example and saved them in my "test" directory, and also created a version of your "old/new names" file. The column "new" was changed to "location" for simplicity:

```
library(readxl)
names_list <- read_excel("c:/test/names_list.xlsx") # old/new .xlsx names

#   SN_Number location   
# 1 65_sample S1_5
# 2 75_sample S1_10 
# 3 85_sample S1_20

# Create empty df
BF_soil_temp_21 <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=0, ncol=4))
colnames(BF_soil_temp_21) <- c("DateTime", 
                               "Unit",
                               "Value",
                               "location")

# Loop through file names, add new "location" column, and add to "BF_soil_temp_21"
for(i in 1:nrow(names_list)) {

  temp <- read_excel(paste0("c:/test/", names_list[i,1], ".xlsx"))
  temp$location <- names_list[i,2] # Add and populate location column
  BF_soil_temp_21 <- data.frame(rbind(BF_soil_temp_21, temp))) # rbind temp to BF_soil_temp_21

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I am having an issue with the for loop as it is creating a dataframe with only the first file, but I suspect this is an issue with my file setup.

Answer (score 0):

As an update, the following approach using match worked for my purposes:

```r
BF_soil_temp_21$trt <- Trt_list_BF21$Trt[match(BF_soil_temp_21$plot, Trt_list_BF21$Plot)]
```

In this case, `BF_soil_temp_21` was my original df and `Trt_list_BF21` was the df used as a key (where SN was linked to location).